# Subclass widget to insert other widgets in it

Tags: c++, qt, subclass

Is it possible to subclass a widget like a `QTextBrowser` that way I could insert another widget somehow, perhaps like this:

```
SubClassedTextBrowser *tb = new SubClassedTextBrowser();
this->layout().addWidget(tb);
tb->addWidget(new QPushButton("Push me"));
```

I know how to subclass a `QTextBrowser` to edit or add methods, but this particular case I am stumbling.

I don't want to have a window with a vertical layout where I first add a TextBrowser and behind it (after it) a PushButton. My goal is to add widgets to the textBrowser itself, so that I can write text into the TextBrowser before and after the PushButton and be able to select all text at once. Because if I'd have a second TextBrowser behind the PushButton (in total 3 widgets in a vertical layout) I wouldn't be able to select all the text at once. That's why I'd like to use only one TextBrowser but add the widgets somehow into it. Is this possible with standard Qt?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to split the text browser so that there are widgets in between? Could you post a screen shot of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @thuga He wants a method to insert widgets directly inside a text. I propose to use `QWebView` for it and generate html with buttons. Cons: there are no simple way to interact with this buttons.

Comment: Ok it seems like it isn't possible without big effort. The button itself was only an example for a placeholder for my custom widgets. So I'll use more than one single textbrowser and try to find another solution to to be able to select all text.

Answer (score 1):

yes, Just create a parent widget called "CustomTextBrowserContainer",

then you have to write your own "codes"  that will represent things like "butttons" or whatever
lets say `<button>`

Next, you have to add the paintEvent to the CustomTextBrowser

and finally, inside the paintEvent, you parse the contents of the browser, and for each  you replace it with whitespace equivalent to the size of the button and then draw a button manually.